# ModernUI library without navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, modern-ui

Is it possible to use the [ModernUI library](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui/wiki/Getting-started-without-templates) without the page based navigation (i.e. more as a 1:1 replacement for a regular `Window`)?

`ModernWindow`, as documented, ignores the content and expects a group of navigation lists, and I need to keep the existing architecture of `Window` as it is due to a number of reasons. (`ModernDialog` does not seem to put in place any content restrictions in the way `ModernWindows` does, but is, of course, a dialog.)

Comment: Do you mean, you want to use only layout of the Modern UI Window?

Comment: I would like to use the style (this is possible using declarations in app.xaml alone) and the window customization (i.e. the adapted title bar).